# How to output as a whole

Tags: java

I have my code below;

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main{
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
       int first = scan.nextInt();
        for(int i = 1; i <= first; i++){
            
            String max = scan.next();
            
            
            boolean check = false;
            boolean f = false;
            
            for(int x = 0; x < max.length(); x++){
                if(Character.isLetter(max.charAt(x))){
                    if(!check){
                        check = true;
                    }
            }
            else if(Character.isDigit(max.charAt(x))){
              int second = (int)max.charAt(x);
                if(!check || second%2 == 0){
                    f = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if(max.charAt(x) == '#' || max.charAt(x) == '_'){
                if(!check){
                check = true;
            }
        }
        else if(Character.isDigit(max.charAt(x))){
            int second = (int)max.charAt(x);
             if(!check || second%2 == 0){
                 f = true;
                 break;
             }
        }
        else if(max.charAt(x) == '#' ||max.charAt(x) == '_'){
            if(!check){
                check = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            f = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if(f){
        System.out.println("Case #" + i + ": Not Valid");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Case #" + i + ": Valid");
    }
}
}
}
```

it is working just fine, but I wanted it to output like this

SAMPLE INPUT

1

Hi

123hi

yes_sir

SAMPLE OUTPUT

Case #1: VALID

Case #2: INVALID

Case #3: VALID

not like this

INPUT

3

Valid

Case #1: VALID

12Price

Case #2: INVALID

item_price

Case #3: VALID

I wanted it to output as a whole not one by one,
I wanted to change it but i don't know how, I'm kinda confused.

Answer (score 1):

Use **java.io.PrintWriter** to buffer your data and use flush method to flush your data

### Code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);//I'm buffering standard output you can use file also

        int first = scan.nextInt();
        for(int i = 1; i <= first; i++){

            String max = scan.next();

            boolean check = false;
            boolean f = false;

            for(int x = 0; x < max.length(); x++){
                if(Character.isLetter(max.charAt(x))){
                    if(!check){
                        check = true;
                    }
                }
                else if(Character.isDigit(max.charAt(x))){
                    int second = (int)max.charAt(x);
                    if(!check || second%2 == 0){
                        f = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if(max.charAt(x) == '#' || max.charAt(x) == '_'){
                    if(!check){
                        check = true;
                    }
                }
                else if(Character.isDigit(max.charAt(x))){
                    int second = (int)max.charAt(x);
                    if(!check || second%2 == 0){
                        f = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if(max.charAt(x) == '#' ||max.charAt(x) == '_'){
                    if(!check){
                        check = true;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    f = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(f){
                //System.out.println("Case #" + i + ": Not Valid");
                out.println("Case #" + i + ": Not Valid");
            }
            else{
                //System.out.println("Case #" + i + ": Valid");
                out.println("Case #" + i + ": Valid");
            }
        }
        out.flush();//flushes out to standard output
        out.close();//after closing it cannot be used further
    }
}
```

### Output:

```
$ javac Main.java && java Main
2
Hello
Bye
Case #1: Valid
Case #2: Valid
```